# script.js not linked to html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is my html:

Hello i dont get my Javascript working i used codepen.io to write it and it worked. but when i want to use it on my webhost it isnt responding. I try to use it local but its not working. I googled the problem and its proberly something about the place of  but im not sure about that. Can someone help me out and teach me how i can fix this? its a problem that i get alot of times.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Responsive Portfolio Template">
    <meta name="author" content="Sandro Swabedissen">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
      
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="menu">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button> 
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li> 
          </ul> 
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="container-fluid splash" id="splash">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dqhQX0E.png" alt="Portrait of Mr. Swabedissen" class="profile-image"> 
    <h1>HELLO!</h1> 
    <h1 class="intro-text"><span class="lead" id="typed">I am a </span></h1>
    <span class="continue"><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></span>
  </div>
</div>
        <!-- About Section -->
    <section class="success" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>About Me</h2>
                    <hr class="star-light">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <p class="content-text">Hi! I'm Sandro Swabedissen I'm 18 years old and I'm from the Netherlands and I live in Apeldoorn. I study IT support at ROC Aventus in Deventer.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p class="content-text">I like to Photograph and longboarding and basic website coding. I spent most of my time behind the desk or hanging out with my friends.</p>
             </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center contact-button">
                    <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact Me
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<!-- Portfolio -->
    <div class="container-fluid portfolio-container-holder content-section" id="portfolio">
        <div class="portfolio-container container">
            <h1 class="text-center">My Portfolio</h1>
      <hr class="star-portfolio">
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/145335/responsive-vs-adaptive-design-compressor.jpg" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/145335/responsive-vs-adaptive-design-compressor.jpg" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/145335/responsive-vs-adaptive-design-compressor.jpg" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/145335/responsive-vs-adaptive-design-compressor.jpg" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/145335/responsive-vs-adaptive-design-compressor.jpg" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/145335/responsive-vs-adaptive-design-compressor.jpg" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Contact form -->
    <div class="container-fluid contact-me-container content-section" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="intro-text text-center">Contact Me</h1>
      <hr class="star-light">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email ID">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-default submit-button btn-lg btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container footer-container">
            <div class="row footer-row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-center">
            <h4 class="text-center">Find me here</h4>
                    <address>
                        <strong><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> Swabedissen Inc.</strong><br>Netherlands,<br>Gelderland, Apeldoorn<br><br>
                        <a  class="tel" href="tel:0636597738" type="tel"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i><span> +31 06-36597738</span></a>
                    </address>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 social-section">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h4 class="text-center">Also, I can be found here</h4>
                <div class="text-center social-buttons">
          <a href="https://instagram.com/simplysuvi" class="btn btn-default btn-lg social-button link-instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div><hr class="footer-hr">
            <h4 class="author">Made with <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> by <strong>Sandro Swabedissen</strong></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><hr class="copyright">
      <h4><i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> COPYRIGHTS 2012 ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</h4>
        </div>
    </footer>

    
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my css:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menu
{
  background-color: #ffffff79;
}

.starter-template {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.navbar-nav { 
  float:right;
  text-align:center;
}
ul.navbar-nav li 
{
  padding: 0 10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:767px)
{ ul.navbar-nav { float:none; } }
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.navbar-nav li a
{
  color:black!important;
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-family: Century gothic,sans-serif;
  font-weight:600;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover
{
  color:#fff!important;
  background-color:black!important;
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding:10px 15px!important;
}
a.navbar-brand .fa-globe
{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  transition:0.5s ease;
}
a.navbar-brand .fa-globe:hover
{
  color: #3935e6;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: black!important;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #fff!important;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 996px;
}
.splash {
  background:url("https://photos.gurushots.com/unsafe/0x0/351cef5284542fdc28a01f8d2c67c3be/3_ea1623d74f3828136d8e55e6cd5501e1.jpg") no-repeat fixed center bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fff;
}

.splash .container {
  padding-top: 15vh; /* No JS fallback*/
  padding-bottom: 10vh; /* No JS fallback*/
}

.profile-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  max-height:250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.splash h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: .15em;
  text-align: center;
}

.splash .lead, .splash .continue {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
h1.intro-text
{
  margin:0;
  color:#fff;
}
.splash .lead {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-family: Rockwell;
}
.navbar-inverse
{
  border:none!important;
}
@keyframes blink
  {
            0% { opacity:1; }
            50% { opacity:0; }
            100% { opacity:1; }
  }
        @-webkit-keyframes blink
        {
            0% { opacity:1; }
            50% { opacity:0; }
            100% { opacity:1; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes blink
        {
            0% { opacity:1; }
            50% { opacity:0; }
            100% { opacity:1; }
        }
        @-ms-keyframes blink
        {
            0% { opacity:1; }
            50% { opacity:0; }
            100% { opacity:1; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes blink
        {
            0% { opacity:1; }
            50% { opacity:0; }
            100% { opacity:1; }
        }
/* code for animated blinking cursor */
#typed-cursor
{
      opacity: 1;
      font-size: 40px;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: 50;
      -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
      -moz-animation: blink 1s infinite;
      -ms-animation: blink 1s infinite;
      -o-animation: blink 1s infinite;
      animation: blink 1s infinite;
}

.splash .continue {
  font-size: 3em;
  display:block;
}

.splash .continue a {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 40px;
  height:40px;
  font-size:30px;
}
.splash .continue a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}
#about,#portfolio,#contact
{
  padding-top:4em!important;
}
section h2 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
}
section.success {
    color: #fff;
    background: rgb(13, 79, 136);
  padding: 2%;
}

section.success a
{
  color:black;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
section.success a:hover {
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.contact-button
{
  padding-bottom:2%;
}
hr.star-light,hr.star-portfolio {
    margin: 25px auto 30px;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 250px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: solid 3px;
    text-align: center;
}

hr.star-light:after,hr.star-portfolio:after {
    content: "\f005";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -.8em;
    padding: 0 .25em;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 2em;
}

hr.star-light {
    border-color: #fff;
}
hr.star-portfolio {
    border-color: black;
}
hr.star-portfolio:after {
    color: black;
    background-color: #eee;
}
hr.star-light:after {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(13, 79, 136);
}
p.content-text { font-size: 25px; }

/* PORTFOLIO */
.portfolio-card{
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #888888;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;

}

.portfolio-card:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #888888;
  cursor: pointer
}

.portfolio-container-holder{
    background: #eee;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}


.portfolio-card-holder{
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.portfolio-img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.portfolio-img-desc{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

/* Contact */
.contact-me-container{
    padding:3%;
background: rgb(13, 79, 136);
}
.fa-user,.fa-at,.fa-phone
{
  color:black;
}
.submit-button{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* ========================
Footer
======================== */

footer {
  background-color: #2C3E50;
  color:  #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  padding:3%;
}
a.tel,a.tel:hover
{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
}
a.social-button {
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
}
.address-container{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a.link-facebook,a.link-twitter,a.link-codepen,a.link-linkedin,a.link-instagram
{
  transition:0.4s ease;
}
a.link-twitter
{
  color:#1DA1F2;
}
a.link-facebook
{
 color: #3b5998;
}
a.link-linkedin
{
  color:#007bb6;
}
a.link-instagram
{
  color:#e95950;
}
a.link-facebook:hover{
    background-color: #3b5998;
    color: #fff;
}

a.link-twitter:hover{
    background-color: #1DA1F2;
    color: #fff;
}

a.link-codepen:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
}

a.link-linkedin:hover{
    background-color: #007bb6;
    color: #fff;
}
a.link-instagram:hover{
    background-color: #e95950;
    color: #fff;
}
.btn-default {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: transparent!important;
}
.fa-heart {
  color:#f32323;
}
h4.author
{
  letter-spacing:4px;
}
hr.footer-hr
{
  width:150px;
}
hr.copyright
{
  opacity:0.4;
}
```

Here is my script.js:

```js
$( window ).resize( function() {
  centerSplash();
});

!function($){

    "use strict";

    var Typed = function(el, options){

        // chosen element to manipulate text
        this.el = $(el);
        // options
        this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.typed.defaults, options);

        // text content of element
        this.text = this.el.text();

        // typing speed
        this.typeSpeed = this.options.typeSpeed;

        // amount of time to wait before backspacing
        this.backDelay = this.options.backDelay;

        // input strings of text
        this.strings = this.options.strings;

        // character number position of current string
        this.strPos = 0;

        // current array position
        this.arrayPos = 0;

        // current string based on current values[] array position
        this.string = this.strings[this.arrayPos];

        // number to stop backspacing on.
        // default 0, can change depending on how many chars
        // you want to remove at the time
        this.stopNum = 0;

        // Looping logic
        this.loop = this.options.loop;
        this.loopCount = this.options.loopCount;
        this.curLoop = 1;
        if (this.loop === false){
            // number in which to stop going through array
            // set to strings[] array (length - 1) to stop deleting after last string is typed
            this.stopArray = this.strings.length-1;
        }
        else{
            this.stopArray = this.strings.length;
        }

        // All systems go!
        this.init();
        this.build();
    }

        Typed.prototype =  {

            constructor: Typed

            , init: function(){
                // begin the loop w/ first current string (global self.string)
                // current string will be passed as an argument each time after this
                this.typewrite(this.string, this.strPos);
            }

            , build: function(){
                this.el.after("<span id=\"typed-cursor\">|</span>");
            }

            // pass current string state to each function
            , typewrite: function(curString, curStrPos){

                // varying values for setTimeout during typing
                // can't be global since number changes each time loop is executed
                var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 30)) + this.typeSpeed;
                var self = this;

                // ------------- optional ------------- //
                // backpaces a certain string faster
                // ------------------------------------ //
                // if (self.arrayPos == 1){
                //  self.backDelay = 50;
                // }
                // else{ self.backDelay = 500; }

                // containg entire typing function in a timeout
                setTimeout(function() {

                    // make sure array position is less than array length
                    if (self.arrayPos < self.strings.length){

                        // start typing each new char into existing string
                        // curString is function arg
                        self.el.text(self.text + curString.substr(0, curStrPos));

                        // check if current character number is the string's length
                        // and if the current array position is less than the stopping point
                        // if so, backspace after backDelay setting
                        if (curStrPos > curString.length && self.arrayPos < self.stopArray){
                            clearTimeout(clear);
                            var clear = setTimeout(function(){
                                self.backspace(curString, curStrPos);
                            }, self.backDelay);
                        }

                        // else, keep typing
                        else{
                            // add characters one by one
                            curStrPos++;
                            // loop the function
                            self.typewrite(curString, curStrPos);
                            // if the array position is at the stopping position
                            // finish code, on to next task
                            if (self.loop === false){
                                if (self.arrayPos === self.stopArray && curStrPos === curString.length){
                                    // animation that occurs on the last typed string
                                    // fires callback function
                                    var clear = self.options.callback();
                                    clearTimeout(clear);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // if the array position is greater than array length
                    // and looping is active, reset array pos and start over.
                    else if (self.loop === true && self.loopCount === false){
                        self.arrayPos = 0;
                        self.init();
                    }
                        else if(self.loopCount !== false && self.curLoop < self.loopCount){
                            self.arrayPos = 0;
                            self.curLoop = self.curLoop+1;
                            self.init();
                        }

                // humanized value for typing
                }, humanize);

            }

            , backspace: function(curString, curStrPos){

                // varying values for setTimeout during typing
                // can't be global since number changes each time loop is executed
                var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 30)) + this.typeSpeed;
                var self = this;

                setTimeout(function() {

                    // ----- this part is optional ----- //
                    // check string array position
                    // on the first string, only delete one word
                    // the stopNum actually represents the amount of chars to
                    // keep in the current string. In my case it's 14.
                     if (self.arrayPos == 1, 2, 3, 4){
                        self.stopNum = 0;
                     }
                    //every other time, delete the whole typed string
                     //else{
                        //self.stopNum = 0;
                     //}

                    // ----- continue important stuff ----- //
                    // replace text with current text + typed characters
                    self.el.text(self.text + curString.substr(0, curStrPos));

                    // if the number (id of character in current string) is
                    // less than the stop number, keep going
                    if (curStrPos > self.stopNum){
                        // subtract characters one by one
                        curStrPos--;
                        // loop the function
                        self.backspace(curString, curStrPos);
                    }
                    // if the stop number has been reached, increase
                    // array position to next string
                    else if (curStrPos <= self.stopNum){
                        clearTimeout(clear);
                        var clear = self.arrayPos = self.arrayPos+1;
                        // must pass new array position in this instance
                        // instead of using global arrayPos
                        self.typewrite(self.strings[self.arrayPos], curStrPos);
                    }

                // humanized value for typing
                }, humanize);

            }

        }

    $.fn.typed = function (option) {
        return this.each(function () {
          var $this = $(this)
            , data = $this.data('typed')
            , options = typeof option == 'object' && option
          if (!data) $this.data('typed', (data = new Typed(this, options)))
          if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
        });
    }

    $.fn.typed.defaults = {
        strings: ["Hello, hola, hi! ", "Welcome to my website ", "Go on, scroll down", ":)"],
        // typing and backspacing speed
        typeSpeed: 50, // speed decreases as number increased
        // time before backspacing
        backDelay: 100,
        // loop
        loop: true,
        // false = infinite
        loopCount: false,
        // ending callback function
        callback: function(){ null }
    }


}(window.jQuery);


$(function(){

        $("#typed").typed({
            strings: ["web developer","photographer","human being"], //Strings to display when typing
            typeSpeed: 40,
            backDelay: 600,
            loop: true,
            // defaults to false for infinite loop
            loopCount: false,
            callback: function(){ foo(); }
        });

        function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }

    });
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend posting the error you get on console, as it can help people to answer your question faster.

Comment: Its not something about the console but about the code. Cause java isnt working on the host and on my local computer. But it does work when i put my code in CodePen.io

Comment: It is unclear from the question what is not working. Your server might be not serving javascripts, your javascript might be in the wrong place (needs to be in the same directory as the html), or your web host might be disallowing script execution, or your javascript might not be executing at the proper time. Please provide the exact error that the browser produces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix your web page for you, but there is one thing I cannot fix. I have no idea what you wanted to do with this part of your `script.js`:

```js
$( window ).resize( function() {
  centerSplash();
});
```

There is no function anywhere called `centerSplash`. Most of your errors were in your html file, but I fixed them all. The main errors were that you were importing 2 different versions of jQuery and your scripts/links were trying to access local files when they were being run directly through the file system.

With that out of the way, here is your fixed HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Responsive Portfolio Template">
    <meta name="author" content="Sandro Swabedissen">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
      
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="menu">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button> 
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li> 
          </ul> 
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="container-fluid splash" id="splash">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dqhQX0E.png" alt="Portrait of Mr. Swabedissen" class="profile-image"> 
    <h1>HELLO!</h1> 
    <h1 class="intro-text"><span class="lead" id="typed">I am a </span></h1>
    <span class="continue"><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a></span>
  </div>
</div>
        <!-- About Section -->
    <section class="success" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>About Me</h2>
                    <hr class="star-light">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <p class="content-text">Hi! I'm Sandro Swabedissen I'm 18 years old and I'm from the Netherlands and I live in Apeldoorn. I study IT support at ROC Aventus in Deventer.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p class="content-text">I like to Photograph and longboarding and basic website coding. I spent most of my time behind the desk or hanging out with my friends.</p>
             </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center contact-button">
                    <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact Me
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<!-- Portfolio -->
    <div class="container-fluid portfolio-container-holder content-section" id="portfolio">
        <div class="portfolio-container container">
            <h1 class="text-center">My Portfolio</h1>
      <hr class="star-portfolio">
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/145335/responsive-vs-adaptive-design-compressor.jpg" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/145335/responsive-vs-adaptive-design-compressor.jpg" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/145335/responsive-vs-adaptive-design-compressor.jpg" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/145335/responsive-vs-adaptive-design-compressor.jpg" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/145335/responsive-vs-adaptive-design-compressor.jpg" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 portfolio-card-holder">
                    <div class=" portfolio-card">
                        <img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/145335/responsive-vs-adaptive-design-compressor.jpg" alt="Portfolio" class="img-responsive portfolio-img">

                        <div class="portfolio-img-desc">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Contact form -->
    <div class="container-fluid contact-me-container content-section" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="intro-text text-center">Contact Me</h1>
      <hr class="star-light">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email ID">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-default submit-button btn-lg btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container footer-container">
            <div class="row footer-row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 text-center">
            <h4 class="text-center">Find me here</h4>
                    <address>
                        <strong><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> Swabedissen Inc.</strong><br>Netherlands,<br>Gelderland, Apeldoorn<br><br>
                        <a  class="tel" href="tel:0636597738" type="tel"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i><span> +31 06-36597738</span></a>
                    </address>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 social-section">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h4 class="text-center">Also, I can be found here</h4>
                <div class="text-center social-buttons">
          <a href="https://instagram.com/simplysuvi" class="btn btn-default btn-lg social-button link-instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div><hr class="footer-hr">
            <h4 class="author">Made with <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> by <strong>Sandro Swabedissen</strong></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><hr class="copyright">
      <h4><i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> COPYRIGHTS 2012 ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</h4>
        </div>
    </footer>

    
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`style.css` is the same.

`script.js` will work as is, but I would comment out those first three lines until you figure out what it is you want to do with the `centerSplash` thing.

Nice page btw.

Comment: Thanks for your help! it works fine now! Im new to coding and only understand the basics of HTML and CSS any good suggestion about where i can learn basics about java?

Comment: Since this is about front-end development, I'm assuming you meant JavaScript, not Java. Java is a COMPLETELY DIFFERENT language.
I'm pretty experienced in both, and in my opinion, the best place to start out learning JavaScript for someone like you who is familiar with HTML/CSS is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide). Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You are running the script in `head` and expecting all of the document's content to be loaded (for example the `typed` div). This explains why it works in Codepen but not in your local environment, because Codepen runs the javascript after the html content has been loaded.

To solve this, you can use an event listener to wait for the document to fully load.

The document is not loaded by the time you are trying to find an element with the id `typed`. Change it to

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#typed").typed({
            strings: ["web developer","photographer","human being"], //Strings to display when typing
            typeSpeed: 40,
            backDelay: 600,
            loop: true,
            // defaults to false for infinite loop
            loopCount: false,
            callback: function(){ foo(); }
        });

        function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }

    });
```

[Docs on `document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Well im not really good with java this is my first time actually using it. I changed the code but its still not working or responding.

Comment: @Sandro A) Java != JavaScript B) Please tell me what you mean by "not working or responding". What errors show in the console?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/1b8b28bb4fad6dda7197fb4345b61a40

https://gyazo.com/f05be7170360a4aa3686081e9e67fb58

Comment: Every single one of those errors is a [linter](https://www.codereadability.com/what-are-javascript-linters/) error. This code should work fine. The error you are getting from the linter are because the linter does not know that you are using jQuery.

Comment: So ill have to add an:

```<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>```

Comment: @Sandro Open your console (Most of them use the F12 as shortcut)  inside your browser and show the info you get there. By this way you can provide a better context about what occurs. (You can also edit your question with this info)

Comment: @Sandro You already have that in your code. You should be able to run it fine, as like I said earlier those are [linter](https://www.codereadability.com/what-are-javascript-linters/) errors, not actual ones. Just try running the html file in your browser.